# Date of trigger field a day ahead

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-field, date

I have a field Last_Call_c date and has a trigger but the date request is a day early.

My code

```
trigger CallDate on Task (after insert, after update, after delete) 
{
    Set<Id> con_set = new Set<Id>();
    List<Contact> con_list = new List<Contact>();
    for( Task T: Trigger.new )
    {
        // if(String.valueof(T.whoid).startsWith('003') && T.Status=='Completed' && T.Subject=='Call' )
        {
            con_set.add(T.whoid);
        }
    }

    for(AggregateResult aggregateResult:[SELECT max(createdDate)MaxCDate,whoid FROM Task WHERE whoid IN: con_set AND Status ='Completed' AND (subject LIKE 'call%' OR subject LIKE 'outbound%') group By whoid])
    {
        con_list.add(new Contact(Id=(id)aggregateResult.get('whoid'),Last_Call__c=date.valueof(aggregateResult.get('MaxCDate'))));

    }
    try
    {
        if(con_list !=null && con_list.size()>0)
        {
            update con_list;
        }
    } Catch(Exception ee){
        system.debug('Exception ***'+ee.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: issue may be with timeZone

Comment: unfortnately, thats the first thing I looked at.  I think its in the trigger.  I just dont know what causing it because I look at the activity history date that's right.  It's this trigger maybe.

Comment: Did you try to use the convertTimezone() function?
SELECT max(convertTimezone(createdDate))MaxCDate

Comment: I agree with Ratan and crmprogdev that this is probably a timezone issue. This trigger will execute in the context of whoever created that task. Now, my question is: who is creating the task? Is it the same end user who sees the date being off by a day, or is the task being created by some other automated process (ie: via partner WSDL). In the latter case, the user for the automated process may have a different timezone to the end user and that would cause your dates to be off (especially if the difference is big).

Comment: @MartinLezer I tried that and I got this error.
Error: Compile Error: timezone conversion only applies to date aggregate functions at line 13 column 42

Answer (score 3):

You're querying the `createdDate` which is a `DateTime` field, then converting it to a `Date` field. From the SOQL and SOSL reference:

> SOQL queries in a client application return dateTime field values as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) values. You can use
>   convertTimezone() in a date function to convert dateTime fields to the user’s time zone.

As such, without doing the `Timezone` conversion before you do the `Date` conversion, that would very easily cause your dates to be a day off; depending of course on your location and the time of day for the records.

Comment: I tried using the convertTimezone() but is currently giving me error.

Comment: Error: Compile Error: timezone conversion only applies to date aggregate functions at line 13 column 42

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like you did that afterward instead of in your query? At least that sounds like what the message is telling you. You need to use a different method to convert it outside of your query.